# error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'dist'

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

For some reason I'm getting this error `error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'dist'`, despite `dist` being a folder. Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to fix this?

tsconfig:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5" ,
        "lib": [
            "es2019",
            "dom"
        ],
        "allowJs": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,

        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true ,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true ,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": ["node_modules/"],
    "include": ["main.ts"]
}
```

This is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"typeRoots": [
     "./"
],
```

Your typeRoots is mapped to your root folder so it will think that `./dist` and `./node_modules` will include definition files which is incorrect. I would suggest putting it in a `./typings` folder to avoid this problem.

- Move your `glsl.d.ts` file to a folder called `./typings`
- Change the typeRoots value to `['./typings']`
- Run `tsc` and it will no longer complain

Answer (score 0):

I am using NestJS and the solution for me was to add  `"typeRoots": [],`
in `tsconfig.json`. I solved it accidentally and don't know why this works.